# Tool to generate human readable JSON of Substrate node metadata from a file?

Tags: metadata, json, subwasm

The cli tool `subwasm` can get the metadata from a live node (url) and output JSON that is human readable.  However, to troubleshoot various issues, I need a tool that generates human readable JSON from hex encoded SCALE metadata in a file.  i.e. it doesn't go to a live node.

e.g.  The hex encoded SCALE data in a JSON-RPC result. It doesn't matter if the tool uses the result data or the whole JSON-RPC json result.  I just need it to output it in human readable form.

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x6d6574610e3904000c1c73705f636f72651863727970746f2c4163636f756e7449643332000004000401205b75383b2033325d0000040000032000000008000800000503000c08306672616d655f73797374656d2c4163636f756e74496e666f0814496e64657801102c4163636f756e74446174610114001401146e6f6e6365100114496e646578000124636f6e73756d657273100120...etc............
```

Is there a tool that does this?

Comment: Where did you get that "hex encoded metadata" file from? What encoding is it actually? Just Hex UTF-8 or hex SCALE?

Comment: hex SCALE.  I got it from `cargo run metadata`

Comment: e.g.  it looks like this
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x6d6574610e3904000c1c73705f636f72651863727970746f2c4163636f756e7449643332000004000401205b75383b2033325d0000040000032000000008000800000503000c08306672616d655f73797374656d2c4163636f756e74496e666f0814496e64657801102c4163636f756e74446174610114001401146e6f6e6365100114496e646578000124636f6e73756d657273100120.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subwasm works on a whole runtime block. It could probably be changed, but I rather created [submeta](https://github.com/ggwpez/submeta).
You can use it with a stored encoded metadata from an RPC like this:

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getMetadata"}' https://rpc.polkadot.io:443 |\
jq '.result' -r |\
submeta pallets --with-storage
```

or from a local file:

```bash
cat metadata.json | jq metadata.json '.result' -r | submeta pallets --with-storage
```